# Did King Abijam and King Asa have the same mother? The Bible says their mother is Maacah of Abishalom but says the two kings are father and son?

Tags: sin, 1-kings, genealogy, grace, adultry

> ”Now in the eighteenth year of King Jeroboam the son of Nebat, Abijam
> began to reign over Judah. He reigned for three years in Jerusalem.
> **His mother's name was Maacah the daughter of Abishalom**.“ ‭‭ ”And he walked in all the sins that his father did before him, and his
> heart was not wholly true to the Lord his God, as the heart of David
> his father. Nevertheless, for David's sake the Lord his God **gave him
> a lamp** in Jerusalem, **setting up his son after him**, and
> establishing Jerusalem, because David did what was right in the eyes
> of the Lord and did not turn aside from anything that he commanded him
> all the days of his life, except in the matter of Uriah the Hittite.
> And Abijam slept with his fathers, and they buried him in the city of
> David. **And Asa his son reigned in his place.** In the twentieth year
> of Jeroboam king of Israel, Asa began to reign over Judah, and he
> reigned forty-one years in Jerusalem. **His mother's name was Maacah
> the daughter of Abishalom.** And Asa did what was right in the eyes of
> the Lord, as David his father had done.“ ‭‭1 Kings‬ ‭15‬:‭1‬-‭5‬,
> ‭8‬-‭11‬ ‭ESV

It sounds like their mother is the same person but the text makes it rather clear that Abijam and Asa are father and son, saying in 2 places “son” and also “gave him a lamp in Jerusalem” which I believe is terminology meaning leaving a descendant.

So did Abijam sleep with his mother to produce the next king of Judah or is there something I’m missing?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old "chestnut' of a problem that many commentators have wrestled with.  For example, Ellicott says this:

> (1 Kings 15:10) *His mother’s name was Maachah*.—Maachah was (see 1Kings
> 15:2) the wife of Rehoboam, and, therefore, grandmother of Asa. She
> appears, however, still to have retained the place of “queen-mother,”
> to the exclusion of the real mother of the king.

Similarly, The Cambridge commentary suggests this:

> 10. *And his mother’s name was Maachah, the daughter of Abishalom* The most probable explanation of this clause, which is the same as in 1
>     Kings 15:2 above, is that the word ‘mother’ is here used for
>     ‘grandmother,’ and that Asa’s own mother sank into small importance in
>     comparison with her mother-in-law.

The Pulpit commentary offers more detail:

> Because the mother of the king, and not the grandmother, enjoyed the
> dignity and position of Gebirah (ver. 13; 2 Chronicles 15:16). Some
> would read for Abishalom, Uriel of Gibeah; others, strengthened by the
> Michaiah of 2 Chronicles 13:2, think the historian mistaken in
> mentioning the name of Abijam's mother (ver. 2; 2 Chronicles 11:21) as
> Maachah. The difficulty by no means admits of a ready solution, but
> perhaps the best explanation is that the grandmother, Maachah,
> Rehoboam's favourite wife, retained her position, possibly by force of
> character, or because Asa's mother was dead.

In brief, we do not have enough information to fully resolve this problem.